# What is the meaning of "as we moonshine and molly" in Rihanna's Diamonds?

Tags: meaning, lyrics

> Palms rise to the universe
>   **As we moonshine and molly**
>   Feel the warmth, we’ll never die
>   We’re like diamonds in the sky

In the above part of Rihanna's Diamonds song, what does she mean by "as we moonshine and molly"?

Comment: Interpreting song lyrics isn't part of the job description here, especially for contemporary stuff that seems prima facie incomprehensible. Maybe a beautiful woman with a good voice can get away with singing this kind of stuff for money, but I wouldn't pay to listen to it. "Feel the warmth"? Rod McKuen. "We'll never die"? Schizophrenia. "Moonshine and molly"? Does anybody really care?

Comment: Nice song; sadly, off-topic on ELU.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The OED gives two definitions for the verb *moonshine*. The first is ‘To cheat or deceive (a person) with appealing and persuasive but empty talk.’ The second is ‘To distil liquor, especially whisky, illicitly.’ *Molly* (same source) can mean ‘To engage in homosexual anal intercourse with’ or it can mean the same as *mollycoddle*, that is, ‘To coddle, pamper; to treat in an over-indulgent or excessively protective way.’

You can take your pick from the meanings given, depending on how you want to interpret the song, or there may be other meanings of which the OED is innocent. Song lyrics are open to all sorts of interpretations, which is why they are generally regarded as off-topic here, so don’t be surprised if the question is closed.

*'Molly' is another name for MDMA or ecstasy - a recreational drug. I suspect Sia is referring to drinking strong whiskey and taking ecstasy (Molly).